# Replace a specific variable in a .cfg file

Tags: php

In my application I have a .cfg file that contains variables like this:

```
variable1=test
variable2=someOtherValue
variable3=somethingElse
```

What I want to do is replace the values for these variables without knowing their position in the text file. I want it to find the variable and replace the value behind it. With something like a function: `updateVariable("variable1", "aNewValue");`

I am working with PHP.

*There is a good chance this question has been asked before, but I wasn't sure what to look up in the search engines*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Function**

```
function updateVariable($filePath, $varName, $newValue) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($filePath);
    preg_match_all("/$varName=.+/i", $contents, $matches);
    foreach ($matches as $find) {
        $replace = $varName . '=' . $newValue . PHP_EOL;
        $contents = str_replace($find, $replace, $contents);
    }
    $fh = fopen($filePath, 'wb');
    fwrite($fh, $contents);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

**Usage**

```
updateVariable('path/to/your/file.cfg', 'variable1', 'hello');
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but it adds 4 line breaks after the updated variable? It's not really a problem, but would be nice to get that fixed too :)

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen Depends on your OS. Maybe try replacing PHP_EOL with `"\n"` and see if that's better for you. Make sure you use double quotes on that part. If that doesn't add any line breaks, you can also try `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

open your file then, use `str_replace`

```
$mystring = fopen($filename, "wb");
$newstring = str_replace("variable1", "newvalue", $mystring);
```

To get value old value (varaible1) , you have to do a  line by line search

```
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
        echo $line;

    $new_str = substr($line, ($pos = strpos($line, ',')) !== false ? $pos + 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Don't I have to know the old value for it then? Both the variable name and the value it contains? That would be kind of impractical.